# Stripe Pay to Tap SDK with .NET MAUI

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm currently working on a healthcare tech solution using .NET MAUI and looking to integrate Stripe's Tap to Pay SDK into the project. I'm seeking guidance or documentation on the steps required for this integration.

Specifically, I aim to implement Tap to Pay functionality within the healthcare application developed in .NET MAUI. I've reviewed Stripe's documentation but haven't found explicit instructions for .NET MAUI.

Could anyone provide guidance, step-by-step instructions, or relevant resources on integrating Stripe's Tap to Pay SDK with a .NET MAUI application? Any code snippets, examples, or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First I'm hearing of it, but it looks like [.NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui?view=net-maui-8.0) is a cross-platform development pattern similar (in concept) to React Native.

Stripe Tap to Pay ([docs](https://site-admin.stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/setup-reader/tap-to-pay)) support iOS and Android via Stripe's SDKs, so you'll need to determine if/how MAUI supports you setting up bridges to those SDKs to enable the functionality.